# Stop GWT from compiling everytime the server starts

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, wildfly

I've got a [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) web project that I deploy to a [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/) server using [IntelliJ IDEA 14](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

When I deploy the project everything is done very quickly without compiling GWT.

My colleague has got nearly the identical set-up. But every time he starts the server GWT compiles anew. Unfortunately this takes ages.

How can he stop GWT from compiling on every server statup? He has got a copy of my IntelliJ IDEA project but it's still not working. Are there some IntelliJ settings or plugins that we miss?

Comment: Are you using SuperDevMode ? What version of GWT are you using?

Comment: @Simon-Pierre No, I am not using SuperDevMode. The GWT version is 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I know that by default when creating a configuration in Intellij, it adds a make job before launching. Probably that what makes the application compile. So remove the make call.

[image]

Comment: I have the `Make` call as well and I dont' have the problem that GWT compiles for every server start.